# react-google-charts.com is that posible to add tootip on legend?

Tags: tooltip, legend, react-google-charts

## Title:react-google-charts.com is that posible to add tootip on legend ?

Title:react-google-charts.com is that posible to add tootip on legend ?
**utl: https://www.react-google-charts.com/**

code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";
export function App() {
  return (
    <Chart
      chartType="BarChart"
      width="100%"
      height="400px"
      diffdata={diffdata}
      options={options}
    />
  );
}
```